# How to open iOS app when user scans a QR Code with an URL in it

Tags: ios, xamarin, qr-code, ios-universal-links

I want to create a QR Code that contains a URL like https://example.com in it and when an user scans that, if they have the app installed on the phone, to open the app instead of going to the browser. Is that possible? I've looked at App Links and Universal Links and I can't see to get it to trigger off of a QR Code or with HTTPS instead of some custom URL.

Comment: I think this depends on the qr reader which is used. If the reader uses an open url with registered scheme the app should start (for https use an universal link)

Comment: @OliverM I haven't seen a QR Reader that works for me on iOS.  I have clicked the link in my email and it will load the app instead. (actually only worked once.)

Comment: iOS universal links is what you want. If you have to have `apple-app-site-association` on your secure web site, add the correct entitlements to your iOS app and handle the `NSUserActivity` in your app delegate. Apple has a complete guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW2

Comment: @SushiHangover  I have that set up on my site.  Verified it with https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ but it only seems to work once and then stop working and has never worked from a QR code and I have tried multiple readers.

Comment: @Matronix QR code or not, does opening `https://mywebsite.com` on your device open your app or not?

Comment: @SushiHangover  I have it now loading if I click the link in my email or if I go to a browser and to the link...but a QR code that contains that URL does not work.

Comment: @Matronix If the QR Reader you are using is not checking `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionUniversalLinksOnly` and loading the url into its own web view, your app will not be loaded, of course I'm assuming your qr code is correct and is ***not*** a redirect (no 30x will open your universal link app)

Comment: @SushiHangover do you have a recommendation for iOS QR Reader that would perform correctly to see what my issue is?  And my QR code is just  https://site.mywebsite.com

Comment: Well, what would you mean by 'a QR reader that would perform correctly'? You don't know which one your users will use, so while I ubderstand your desire to test this, you should rather concentrate on covering all your bases in my opinion - if most readers rather open the website, make sure that it is responsive, looks good across all devices, conveys the message, has appropriate links, information, instruction, etc.

Comment: @Losiowaty all other ways work except for with the QR. I want to test it with a Reader that does the checking that is needed to just make sure that the feature works if everything is there. I know that the users will use whatever they have and most likely this feature won't work for them.

Answer (score 10):

Scanning QR code containing a URL with standard Camera app results in prompt to open the link in Safari. If the link in question is Universal Link and you do have the associated app installed, the prompt shows your app instead of Safari. If a user taps on that prompt your app is brought to foreground and  `application(_:userActivity:restorationHandler:)` is called. It seems like it's not documented anywhere, but most likely it's an intended behavior and it's definitely working.